# Ruby: Having trouble pulling data from this class

Tags: ruby, class

So here's the output of `inspect` on a class:

```
<Recurly::BillingInfo::CreditCard:0x1036a8a98 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"month"=>1, "last_four"=>"1", "type"=>"bogus", "year"=>2010}>
```

I'm trying to get the `type` attribute but seems that might be some sort of reserved word?

Here's the full rundown of what I'm trying to do

```
@charges = Recurly::BillingInfo.find('123')
@charges.credit_card.type
```

So, how can I get `type` from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see what methods are available to you:

```
@charges.credit_card.methods
```

Anyway I believe this should work for you:

```
@charges.credit_card.attributes['type']
```

Answer (score 2):

In ActiveRecord "type" as an attribute is reserved for Single Table Inheritance associations I believe.

You may need to alias the name, or create a "card_type" attribute in your migration rather than a "type" attribute.